# Python: process array faster

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I have to process a lot of arrays, they contain 512x256 pixel-like data, however most entries are `0`, so I want to only save the non-zero values, i.e.:

```
import numpy as np
import time

xlist=[]
ylist=[]
zlist=[]

millis = time.time()*1000
ar = np.zeros((512,256),dtype=np.uint16)

for x in range(0,512):
    for y in range(0,256):
        if (0<ar[x][y]<1000):
            xlist.append(x)
            ylist.append(y)
            zlist.append(ar[x][y])

print time.time()*1000-millis
```

this takes about 750ms on my pc. Is there a way to do this faster? I have to process tens of thousands of these pixel arrays.

Comment: Looks like you're dealing with sparse matrices. Scipy gives you some class types to choose from: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html

Comment: In general, if you can avoid writing loops when dealing with numpy arrays you can get much faster performance.  As a side note, if this is python 2.x, just changing `range` to `xrange` could get you a tiny performance increase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
ar = np.zeros((512,256),dtype=np.uint16)

# there should be something here to fill ar    

xs = np.arange(ar.shape[0])
ys = np.arange(ar.shape[1])

check = (0 < ar) & (ar < 1000)
ind = np.where( check )
xlist = xs[ ind[0] ]
ylist = ys[ ind[1] ] 
zlist = ar[ check ]
```

Answer (score 3):

SciPy provides very good support for sparse matrices, which should provide a good solution to your problem. Check out the documentation of the scipy.sparse module [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html).

To convert your numpy array to a coordinate-based (COO) sparse matrix as you do with your code above, you can proceed as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

#your original matrix
A  = numpy.array([[1,0,3],[0,5,6],[0,0,9]])

#We let scipy create a sparse matrix from your data
sA = sparse.coo_matrix(A)

#The x,y,z

xlist,ylist,zlist = sA.row,sA.col,sA.data

print (xlist,ylist,zlist)

#This will print: (array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2], dtype=int32), array([0, 2, 1, 2, 2], dtype=int32), array([1, 3, 5, 6, 9]))
```

Since scipy code usually is highly optimized this should run faster than your looping solution (I didn't check it though).